# Scratchpad for testing post formatting

Tags: support

Is there a scratchpad for testing post formatting?

I thought I had read something in the past but can't find how.

Comment: Other stacks seem to have a sandbox (e.g. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7183/401) but we do not (or at least I am not aware of any).